# Is it possible to use OR in an xpath query? Want to match 2 different attributes in one query

Tags: xpath

I want do an xpath query that matches two separate attributes.

So I want to match `//div[@class='foo']/` OR `//div[@class='bar']/`

How do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
//div[@class='foo' or @class='bar']
```

Comment: +1 Good answer. Also, this is shorter: `//div[@class[.='foo' or .='bar']]`

Comment: FYI, for those who cannot remember the syntax for various xpath constructs, there's a one-page quick reference card on mulberrytech.com.  Very handy. Find it at http://www.mulberrytech.com/quickref/index.html .

Answer (score 1):

`//div[@class='foo'] | //div[@class='bar']`

Comment: This could be twice slower than @Matthew's solution because it may require to traverse twice the complete tree.

Comment: @Dimitre Thanks. I have just translated the *OR* into `|`, but I thought that Matthew's solution is better. Leaving my answer there for the *or* syntax.

Comment: @styu: `|` has nothing to do with `or`. `|` is the union operator in XPath and a not vey intelligent XPath engine will first evaluate both of its operands before performing the union opertion -- this takes two separate traversals of the whole document tree.

Comment: @Dimitre The logical `or` operator means the union of sets, but thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @styu: `or` is a *boolean* operator, not a set operator. These are very different. This is valid expression: `a=2 or a > 5` . This isn't: `a=2 | a >5`. The latter (correctly) causes a syntax error. Do learn that set arithmetic is something different from boolean arithmetic.

Comment: @Dimitre: Maybe you are correct, but please check out the [Wikipedia article on boolean logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_logic#Terms) - it uses (maybe incorrectly) the term that *"A binary operator applies to two sets. The basic binary operators are logical OR and logical AND. They perform the union and intersection of sets."*.

Comment: @styu: I am a Ph.D in math -- don't need to read ... the Wikipedia. I *know* my subject.

Comment: @Dimitre I didn't want you to read it to learn, just to review it. Now I am sure that this article is wrong, so thank you to point it out.